# How to create this document style?

Tags: tikz-styles, pagestyle

I would be very grateful if you help me to create a document with this style. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way with TikZ and `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum} % some fill text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{Chapter~\thechapter}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{Section~\thesection}
\fancyfoot[LE]{Page~\thepage} 
\fancyfoot[RO]{Page~\thepage} 
\fancyfoot[C]{} 
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[even odd rule,blue!20] (current page.south west)
 rectangle (current page.north east) 
 [rounded corners=1em]
 ([xshift=-0.5em,yshift=-0.5em]current page text area.south west)
 rectangle ([xshift=0.5em,yshift=0.5em]current page text area.north east);
 \draw[blue,dash pattern=on 5pt off 0.5pt,line width=2pt,rounded corners=1em]
 ([xshift=-0.5em,yshift=-0.5em]current page text area.south west)
 rectangle ([xshift=0.5em,yshift=0.5em]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\chapter{pft}
\section{blub}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with gray strip, a bit more generous spacing, and without `fancyhdr` but `tikz` for the header and footer (for finer placement).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum} % some fill text
\pagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\ifodd\value{page}
 \fill[gray!50] (current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=1cm]current
 page.north west);
 \fill[even odd rule,blue!20] ([xshift=1cm]current page.south west)
  rectangle (current page.north east) 
  [rounded corners=1em]
  ([xshift=-1.5em,yshift=-1.5em]current page text area.south west)
  rectangle ([xshift=1.5em,yshift=1.5em]current page text area.north east);
 \node[anchor=south east,text depth=0.25ex] at 
 ([yshift=2em,xshift=1.5em]current page text area.north east){Section~\thesection};
 \node[anchor=north east] at 
 ([yshift=-2em,xshift=1.5em]current page text area.south east){Page~\thepage};
\else
 \fill[gray!50] (current page.south east) rectangle ([xshift=-1cm]current
 page.north east);
 \fill[even odd rule,blue!20] ([xshift=-1cm]current page.south east)
  rectangle (current page.north west) 
  [rounded corners=1em]
  ([xshift=-1.5em,yshift=-1.5em]current page text area.south west)
  rectangle ([xshift=1.5em,yshift=1.5em]current page text area.north east);
 \node[anchor=south west,text depth=0.25ex] at 
 ([yshift=2em,xshift=-1.5em]current page text area.north west){Chapter~\thechapter};
 \node[anchor=north west] at 
 ([yshift=-2em,xshift=-1.5em]current page text area.south west){Page~\thepage};
\fi
 \draw[blue,dash pattern=on 5pt off 1pt,line width=2pt,rounded corners=1em]
 ([xshift=-1.5em,yshift=-1.5em]current page text area.south west)
 rectangle ([xshift=1.5em,yshift=1.5em]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\chapter{pft}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{blub}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note that one can have a seemingly simpler code by just adding the gray bar on the top but I find it cleaner not to overpaint things.)

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you @Schrödinger's cat. And how to get the vertical gray strip on each page please?

Comment: @Gallagher I added a version with this strip.

Comment: Thank you very much @Schrödinger's cat.